# Can we adopt Lucene index to retrieve data from rdf tables?

Tags: zend-lucene

Lucene index can it be merged with b+trees to make the indexing better , inorder to retrieve data from the rdf table? Is there any procedure available?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Siren](http://rdelbru.github.io/SIREn/)
to link the RDF data into Lucene